# I have a program called Super Lab that I need for a research paper in Psychology

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, compatibility

I recently bought a new computer and it claims that I can't install the program due to lack of compatability to a 64 bit system. What can I do?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate?

Comment: More importantly: What version of SuperLab?  The old Win16 SuperLap Pro?  SuperLab 2.0?  SuperLab 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the installer and under the Compatability tab, select Windows XP or whatever is appropriate. Does this software require the use of any serial ports/usb/parallel ports? If not, you can alway use VirtualBox and run Windows XP from within Windows 7 in a virtual environment.